# Summernote image upload not working in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, summernote

I have integrated summernote in my website (built with **Codeigniter**) and for texts it is working fine. But for image upload, there arises the following problem.

Summernote reads the image as base64. Now this works perfectly fine for small images, but once images are large, the image finally does not render due to the huge string created by the base64 in the database.

So I am trying to save the image in my server and then use the link of that image.

Following are the codes:
Script for summernote:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#summernote').summernote({
    height: 300,
    onImageUpload: function(files) {
            sendFile(files[0]);
        }
  });
  function sendFile(file) {
        data = new FormData();
        data.append("files", file);
        upload_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "general/upload_image";
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: "POST",
            url: upload_url,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(url) {
                 $(this).summernote("insertImage", url);

            }
        });
    }
});
```

the php upload_image function:

```
public function upload_image()
{
    if ($_FILES['file']['name']) {
        if (!$_FILES['file']['error']) {
            $name = md5(rand(100, 200));
            $ext = explode('.', $_FILES['file']['name']);
            $filename = $name . '.' . $ext[1];
            $destination = 'http://sitename.com/dist/img/blogimg/' . $filename; //change this directory
            $location = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
            move_uploaded_file($location, $destination);
            echo 'http://sitename.com/dist/img/blogimg/' . $filename;//change this URL
        }
        else
        {
            echo  $message = 'Ooops!  Your upload triggered the following error:  '.$_FILES['file']['error'];
        }
    }
}
```

now, when I click on insert image in summernote or drag and drop an image multiple instances of the following error is shown in the console:

```
>Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined
```

This is what I want to achieve,
N.B. This editor is for a blog.
1. User clicks on insert image and uploads an image from his computer.
2. the image is shown in the editor (but not uploaded to server at this step).
3. When user clicks on submit button, then the image should be saved as an image file in a predefined folder.
4. When the page renders the it should have

```
<img src="mysite.com/path_to_image">
```

now it is something like

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJR....">)
```

Please note, I tried using onImageUpload within callbacks but the result was nothing was actually happening, neither the image was geting uploaded to the editor nor to the folder in the server.

Where am I going wrong....?? Please help me fix this...

Comment: Just a suggestion codeigniter has its own upload library https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: Your initial issue with the size of the base 64 can be fixed by changing to LongText

Comment: @wolfgang1983 that upload lib should be used in upload_image() function right?? could you please provide a sample code to show how to handle the POST data with this upload lib. ?? I am not getting it clearly...

Answer (score 0):

if your summernote version after 0.7

following this

```
$('#summernote').summernote({
                height: 400,
                callbacks: {
                    onImageUpload: function(files, editor, welEditable) {
                        sendFile(files[0]);
                    } 
                }});
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, although I could not find a solution to my problem, I have implemented an alternation solution and it works perfectly, although pt. 3 is not catered to and the image is uploaded to the server in an earlier step. That too can be catered with some js scripts...Will do that later... What I did is I targeted the summernote ids and classes and added my codes in place of theirs...

1. I removed their upload image field by this code:

```css
<style>
/*to disable the upload image from computer uncomment this css code.*/
 .note-group-select-from-files {
  display: none;
}

</style>
```

Next I inserted my HTML below their insert link field this way:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('note-group-image-url')[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend','<p class="sober"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#imageModal"><p>Click here to upoad image</p></i></a></p>');
```

Next I handled the image upload through a modal and wrote a custom js script that copied the image url to the field of .note-image-url

Also I had to customise the javascript of the insert image button of summernote with js so that users can directly click on insert image.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your store/ update controller.
It will detect images in your editor, convert and save it in your server.

```
 $body = $data['content'];
        $doc = new DomDocument;
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $doc->loadHTML($body);      
        $images =  $doc->getelementsbytagname('img');
        define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'assets/images/announcement_img/');

        foreach($images as $k => $img){
            $datas = $img->getattribute('src');

            if (strpos($datas, 'data:image')!==false){
            list($type, $datas) = explode(';', $datas);
            list($media, $format) = explode('/', $type);
            list(, $datas)      = explode(',', $datas);
            $datas = str_replace(' ', '+', $datas);
            $datas = base64_decode($datas);

            $file= UPLOAD_DIR . time().$k.'.'.$format;
            $success = file_put_contents($file, $datas);
            print $success ? $file : '<br><br>Unable to save the file.<br><br>';

            $img->removeattribute('src');
            $img->setattribute('src',base_url().$file);
            }
        }

          
        $body = $doc->savehtml();
        $data['content']=$body;
```